# Accessing results of multiple futures in futurebuilder

Tags: flutter, dart, future, builder

I am extremely new to flutter and need help.

I am running to futures in the Future Builder and then trying to access the documents. Unfortunately I am getting an error, code and errors below. How do I access both the different document snapshots? Should my future methods return something? Is there a better way to do this?

The error is here:

```
snapshot.data[1].data[index].data["fname"]
```

Code:

```
class PostsWidget extends StatefulWidget {

@override
  _PostsWidgetState createState() => _PostsWidgetState();
}

class _PostsWidgetState extends State<PostsWidget> {
  Future getPosts() async {
    var firestore = Firestore.instance;
    QuerySnapshot qn = await firestore.collection("posts").getDocuments();
    return qn.documents;
  }

  Future getUsers() async {
    var firestore = Firestore.instance;
    QuerySnapshot qn = await firestore.collection("users").getDocuments();
    return qn.documents;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: FutureBuilder(
        future: Future.wait([getPosts(), getUsers()]),
        builder: (_, snapshot) {
          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.waiting:
              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            default:
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data[0].length,
                itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                  return Card(
                      child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        color: Color(0xff707070),
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                                child: Text(
                                  snapshot.data[1].data[index].data["fname"],
                                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                                child: Icon(
                                  Icons.info,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ));
                },
              );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Logs/Errors:

```
Class 'List<DocumentSnapshot>' has no instance getter 'data'.
Receiver: Instance(length:1) of '_GrowableList'
Tried calling: data
```

Comment: same problem here

Answer (score 1):

```
snapshot.data[1].data[index].data["fname"]
```

This line should instead be:

```
snapshot.data[1][index].fname
```

where `fname` is a property of the object you are accessing.